# Can I simplify my code so that I am not writing out every letter of the alphabet individually?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am writing a code that loops through the Gettysburg Address and counts the number of occurrences of each letter. The letter is then stored as a key in the dictionary, and the value for each key is the total number of occurrences of that specific value. The Gettysburg Address was split up into three lines for us to loop through. The way I have it written is that I have each line being looped through, but I have no way to add the line occurrences so that I get the total in the dictionary. For instance if in line 1 there are 5 As, in line 2 there are 10 As and in line 3 there are 15 As, the total should be 30 As and the dictionary should be a:30.

Also, in the file we were given there are blank lines in between lines 1 and 2 and in between lines 2 and 3, and I do not know how to delete these lines for purposes of my loop.

Lastly, right now I have written out every letter for the program, but I was wondering if there is an easier way to go about this that could simplify what I have.

```
# Function: readFile
# Parameters: filename
# Return: dictionary
# Detail: Loop through each line of the Gettysburg Address File and count the occurrences of each letter in each line
# Detail: Sum the occurrences of each letter for each line to find the total occurences of each letter for the entire document
# Add the letter and its occurence to a dictionary key:value = letter:occurence
def readFile(filename = "gettysburg.txt"):
    fileIn = open(filename, "r")
    dictionary = {}
    for line in fileIn:
        line.lower()
        letter = "a"
        aCount = line.count("a")
        dictionary[letter] = aCount
        letter = "b"
        bCount = line.count("b")
        dictionary[letter] = bCount
        letter = "c"
        cCount = line.count("c")
        dictionary[letter] = cCount
        letter = "d"
        dCount = line.count("d")
        dictionary[letter] = dCount
        letter = "e"
        eCount = line.count("e")
        dictionary[letter] = eCount
        letter = "f"
        fCount = line.count("f")
        dictionary[letter] = fCount
        letter = "g"
        gCount = line.count("g")
        dictionary[letter] = gCount
        letter = "h"
        hCount = line.count("h")
        dictionary[letter] = hCount
        letter = "i"
        iCount = line.count("i")
        dictionary[letter] = iCount
        letter = "j"
        jCount = line.count("j")
        dictionary[letter] = jCount
        letter = "k"
        kCount = line.count("k")
        dictionary[letter] = kCount
        letter = "l"
        lCount = line.count("l")
        dictionary[letter] = lCount
        letter = "m"
        mCount = line.count("m")
        dictionary[letter] = mCount
        letter = "n"
        nCount = line.count("n")
        dictionary[letter] = nCount
        letter = "o"
        oCount = line.count("o")
        dictionary[letter] = oCount
        letter = "p"
        pCount = line.count("p")
        dictionary[letter] = pCount
        letter = "q"
        qCount = line.count("q")
        dictionary[letter] = qCount
        letter = "r"
        rCount = line.count("r")
        dictionary[letter] = rCount
        letter= "s"
        sCount = line.count("s")
        dictionary[letter] = sCount
        letter = "t"
        tCount = line.count("t")
        dictionary[letter] = tCount
        letter = "u"
        uCount = line.count("u")
        dictionary[letter] = uCount
        letter = "v"
        vCount = line.count("v")
        dictionary[letter] = vCount
        letter = "w"
        wCount = line.count("w")
        dictionary[letter] = wCount
        letter = "x"
        xCount = line.count("x")
        dictionary[letter] = xCount
        letter = "y"
        yCount = line.count("y")
        dictionary[letter] = yCount
        letter = "z"
        zCount = line.count("z")
        dictionary[letter] = bCount
        print(dictionary)

    fileIn.close()

# function: sortKeys
# parameter: Dictionary
# Return: a list of the keys in alphabetical order
# Use the sort method on a list
def sortKeys(dictionary):
    sortedDictionary = sortKeys(dictionary)
    dictionaryList = [[k,v] for k,v in dictionary.items()]

# function: main
# call the readFile function to create a dictionary and store in it a variable
# call the sortKeys function to get a list of sorted keys and store it in a variabel
# Loop through the sorted keys list to print each letter and its frequency (number of times it occurs) using the dictionary.
def main():
    readFile()
    sortKeys()
    print("Displaying letter frequency of the Gettysburg Address")
    for key, value in dictionaryList:
        print(key, value)

main()
```

Comment: Check out [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)s

Answer (score 3):

Certainly:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

def readFile(filename = "gettysburg.txt"):
    with open(filename) as f:
        data = f.read().lower()
        letter_counts = {letter: data.count(letter) for letter in ascii_lowercase}

    return letter_counts
```

First, prefer using `with` to `open`, since if you use `open` you need to remember to close the file object.

Secondly, what you want is basically a *dictionary comprehension*: a way to automatically populate a `dict` with both keys and values that are in some way related.

What this snippet of code does is iterate through `ascii_lowercase`, which is a string containing the lowercase letters of the alphabet. Each letter becomes a key in the resultant `dict`, with the corresponding value the count of that letter in the given text.

Answer (score 1):

Use string.ascii_lowercase

```
import string
...

for letter in string.ascii_lowercase:
    dictionary[letter] = line.count(letter)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! When I made that fix, it only updated the dictionary with the occurrences for the first line. Did I do something wrong? There are 3 lines that need to be looped through.import string
def readFile(filename = "gettysburg.txt"):
    fileIn = open(filename, "r")
    dictionary = {}
    for line in fileIn:
        for letter in string.ascii_lowercase:
            dictionary[letter] = line.count(letter)
    print(dictionary)
    fileIn.close()

Comment: @Jaxon123 looks like you missed line.lower() originally presented in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Counter` for this

```
import re
from collections import Counter

Counter(re.findall(r'[a-z]', open('gettysburg.txt').read()))
```

It works like a dict, where key is the occurrence and value is the amount of it. Checkout the docs: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#counter-objects